# Can users join a meeting created by the Chime API through the Chime app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-chime-sdk

I'm creating a meeting using the Chime API via the SDK and I wanted to make sure that the users can join the meeting I've created, through the Chime web app.

They’re encountering an error telling them that it's an invalid meeting ID.

Is there a way users can join meetings created by the API with the Chime web app or will I need to develop my own client to handle video conference meetings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create your own client.

As per the [docs](https://aws.github.io/amazon-chime-sdk-js/modules/faqs.html#can-i-use-the-amazon-chime-application-to-join-an-amazon-chime-sdk-meeting), the Chime web client can't join meetings created via the Amazon Chime SDK.

> Can I use the Amazon Chime application to join an Amazon Chime SDK meeting?
>
> **The meetings created by the Amazon Chime meetings application and the SDK are distinct.** The Amazon Chime SDK is meant for customers who would like to build the experience into their existing applications and **it is not a means to create an Amazon Chime meeting (with a PIN) that can be joined using the Amazon Chime meetings application**. You cannot use the Amazon Chime SDK to build a custom client to join an Amazon Chime meeting with a PIN.